# How to do ifelse statements in R for more than two options?

Tags: r, if-statement

Suppose I have this:

```
df$color <- ifelse(df$value == 1, "black", "red")
```

I.e. if the `value == 1` in the value column of `df`, then we have black, otherwise we have red. This is fine.

But, how can I do this for values more than 2?

For instance, I want something like:

```
df$color <- if(df$name == 'Greg', 'red'), if(df$name == 'Tom', 'black'), 
  if(df$name == 'Beth', 'white')
```

But this syntax doesn't look right. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::case_when()` for multiple comparisons:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(name = c("Greg", "Tom", "Beth"))


df %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(name == "Greg" ~ "red",
                           name == "Tom" ~ "black",
                           name == "Beth" ~ "White"))
```

Answer (score 1):

See [dplyr::case_when()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html).

For example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(
    name == "Greg" ~ "red",
    name == "Tom" ~ "black",
    name == "Beth" ~ "white",
    TRUE ~ NA_character
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One base R option using `factor`

```
within(
  df,
  color <- c("red", "black", "white")[as.integer(factor(name, levels = c("Greg", "Tom", "Beth")))]
)
```